# VirtualBox Centos снова запускает установку

Tags: linux, centos

CentOS-8-x86_64-1905-dvd1
VirtualBox
Windows 10

Во время установки все ок, но после нажатия на кнопку перезагрузки виртуалка снова просит выбрать установить или запустить тестовый режим...

Что делать ? 
Срочно нужен centos для работы

Comment: Есть ли какие-нибудь ошибки? Или просто перезагрузку всегда просит. Возможно, что он файлы не видит, но точно не знаю.

Comment: @Blacit  Ошибок нет, после нажатия перезагрузки в конце установки, virtualbox снова открывает меню установки и все по новой начинается !

Comment: а если DVD в машине отключить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не изъяли образ установочного диска из виртуального привода.

После установки выключаем машину с только что установленной системой, выбираем ее в менеджере, жмем сверху "Настроить", переходим в "носители", в контроллере IDE выбираем диск, справа от "оптический привод" жмем на значок диска (на скриншоте ниже обведен зеленым), выбираем "изъять привод из диска". После этого стартуем машину и работаем.

[image: Скриншот]